# Being confused with the preposition "on" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, sentence-structure

> In the summer of 1789, rumours swirled about vengeful aristocrats **bent on** the destruction of peasants’ property.

Is "bent on" a collocation here? And the predicate is "swirled"?

Answer (score 3):

See definition 4:

> **[bent (on)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bent)** (adj) : *Determined to do or have.*

I couldn't tell you whether this *idiom* is also a *collocation*, but it's not uncommon.

> In the latest movie in the franchise, the villain -- who we've only caught glimpses of so far -- is revealed in all his power, and **bent on** the destruction of the known universe.

*Swirled* has nothing to do with *bent on*.  In this case it *metaphorically* describes the way the rumors moved through the (French) population

> [**swirl**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swirl) (v): *a: to move with an eddying or whirling motion swirling water, b: to pass in whirling confusion*

In this context it suggests the rumors moved *with great energy*. "Rumors swirled" is, I think, a common collocation, along with similar words like *gossip, speculation, reports*, etc.

> Ever since December, when the Walt Disney Company struck a $52.4 billion deal to acquire most of 21st Century Fox, speculation has **swirled** in Hollywood about James Murdoch’s future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a collocation.

[**to be bent on something/doing something**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bent+on):

> To be very determined to do something, perhaps aggravatingly so.

Usage example:

> I'm bent on getting an A on this exam, so I'll be studying all week.

*Swirled* in this context means *circulated* and it is the past tense of the verb *to swirl* which here is used to describe what the rumours about the vengeful aristocrats were doing: they were circulating. *bent on* describes *vengeful aristocrats*, not *rumours*. To make the sentence more comprehensible, put *that were* after *vengeful aristocrats*:

> In the summer of 1789, rumours swirled about vengeful aristocrats **that were** bent on the destruction of peasants' property.

Speaking grammatically, *rumours* is the subject of the sentence and all the stuff that comes right after it would be the predicate part.

Comment: I think this is more collocation than idiom. The word [_bent_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/bent) means "Determined to take a course of action". There's nothing idiomatic about it; let's not mix apples and oranges.